# Why do we need that the natural numbers are the intersection of all inductive sets in the reals?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

I'm trying to understand this definition. Actually I have seen a lot of questions that describes this topic from the set theoretical point of view, but I would to ask it again from the point of view of humble real analysis.

The stuff is taken from [Stromberg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1470425440) on p. 14.

> Notice that $\mathbb{R}$ is an inductive set and so is $\lbrace t\in \mathbb{R}: t\geq1 \rbrace$ (this is clear). Let $\Theta$ denote the family of all inductive sets of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\mathbb{N} = \bigcap \Theta$.

I think the questions is, what is the proof that $\mathbb{N} = \bigcap \Theta$? If it's too involved, is there an intuitive argument why this is so?

Comment: An inductive set $S$ must contain $0 = \emptyset$ and the successor of any element of $S$. But $\{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$, i.e. the set containing $0$ and closed under succession, is precisely $\mathbb{N}$. So $\mathbb{N}$ is an inductive set and contained in any other inductive set.

Comment: For reference, Stromberg defines a set $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ to be inductive if $1 \in I$ and $x \in I \Rightarrow x+1 \in I$.

Comment: @OlivierRoche perhaps it is because you are considering that zero is in any inductive set. Stromberg does not have this condition (I don't know if it's a derived consequence), so just taking his definition (given by arkeet), the set is inductive.

Comment: The formula $\mathbb{N}=\bigcap\Theta$ in that book is not a theorem, but a definition of $\mathbb{N}$. You don't need to prove it.

Comment: Yeah well.. I was trying to understand the definition and I thought that maybe a proof could clarify such matter.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you agree if $M\in\Theta$ (that is, if $M$ is inductive), then $\mathbb N\subset M$. Therefore, $\mathbb N\subset\bigcap_{M\in\Theta}M$.

On the other hand, since $\mathbb N\in\Theta$, $\mathbb N\supset\bigcap_{M\in\Theta}M$. But the only subset of $\mathbb N$ which is inductive is $\mathbb N$ itself (this follows from the induction principle). And it should be clear that $\bigcap_{M\in\Theta}M$ itself is inductive. So, $\bigcap_{M\in\Theta}M=\mathbb N$